# Unit testing strategies for a layered Java Rest application

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I am currently puzzled regarding the right way I should do **unit** tests. Let's say we have to write **JUnit** tests for a basic Java Rest CRUD application composed of these "common layers" where each layer calls the sub layer:

- Controller layer (ex: AccountRestController.getAccount(id) - returns
  JSON of Account)
- Service layer: (ex: AccountServive.getAccount(id) - returns Account
  object )
- Repository layer (ex: AccountRepository.getAccount(Id) - returns
  Account object )
- Domain layer (ex: Account (id, name) )
- Database table (ex : Account(ID, NAME) )

We would also have the following hypothesis (or restrictions) for the Unit tests (not sure they are appropriate though ?)

- They have to be out of container (no Tomcat\Jetty and no in memory
  database - I guess I would do that in my integration test)
- Use mocking (for example Mockito framework)

So my questions are:

- What is the best way\the right way\the best practices to write **unit
  tests** for this type of application ?
- To be rigorous, do we have to unit test each layer(controller,
  service, repository, domain) independently by mocking each time the
  sub layer
- Would unit testing only the top Rest Controller be enough?
- ... and again ... are my hypothesis appropriate ? (Couldn’t we do
  Unit testing with a container & in memory database?)

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions about what's 'best', 'worst', 'best practice', etc - are not on topic for SO because they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Please update your question so that it's less opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

And I will jump right into the opinionated waters...

I do start writing tests from the bottom layer, and go up, letting the upper layers call the real thing under (as long as it's well contained within my code and/or easy to predict the correct behaviour of lower layer). While this is more like integration test, it works for me.

For me the crucial part about "unit testing" is not to have correct unit tests per these definitions, but to have automated test which can be run fast enough (usually I keep them under 3s in C++ including compilation, in Android+Java I have huge performance problems, as the whole IDE+toolchain is insanely slow, often leading to times like 5+ seconds, on larger projects even hitting 20-30s with gradle build, and I'm trying to run only really basic unit tests, far away from what I do in C++, where my tests are closer to QA set).

AND if they fail, it should be easy to pinpoint the cause of failure. As I call often all layers deep inside, failure in some base class often leads to many failures, but I rarely have problem to identify the cause within a quick look, so this is not worrying me.

When files/databases gets involved, things get usually slower, so I tend to differentiate what is my "unit test" and what belongs to Integration/QA set. Still a in-memory DB can do quite OK for basic things.

I prefer these bastard tests, because when I mock layers under/above the code being tested, it makes me worried I "bake" the expected result into that test too much, missing bugs when I mock it wrong. Plus mocking something is often additional work, so when the run time of tests is a low price to pay, I gladly turn to "integration" like tests.

In Android/Java from what have I seen/used:

- I like Mockito a lot, it somehow fits the way I think about mocking nicely.
- Robolectric (Android specific) is heavy weight, so I use it sparsely, but sometimes it feels like a better fit than mocking pretty much everything.
- Dagger and other dependency injection libs: I can't get to like these, usually they clash with the way I write unit tests, and I don't see any benefit of using them, I prefer to write dependency injection in pure Java, it's almost same number of lines in source, and the source is where I expect it when reading it after few years.
- Bus/Event libraries: these annoy me just as much, I didn't yet figure way how to test event driven code thoroughly and easily, my tests always feels way too much staged and full of assumptions, plus these are sometimes hard to mock.

BTW, if possible, always do unit test while developing (close to TDD approach). Doing unit tests afterwards is usually much more painful, the API is then quite often set (already used by other parts/project), and when you realise it's difficult to test it easily, it's too late already, or big refactoring is next (without tests covering the original version, so error prone).

For a Java Rest CRUD app it sounds to me like most of the API can be tested trough all layers without much performance penalty (with probably the DB mocked/injected/in-memory, and other external systems solved in similar way). But I'm doing in Java only Android stuff, so I don't have direct experience with such scenario.